# Sort an Arraylist by two fields (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist of highscores for a card game I am making. There needs to be a finite limit on the number of scores this arraylist can store, which the user of the system may define (let's say 10 for now). The fields in the objects in the arraylist are the player's name (string), their score (int) and a (almost) unique ID for the player (Long, System.currentTimeMillis()).
The arraylist should be sorted by the score, where the lowest score is the best. However, if all players in the arraylist have the same score and a new player is added with that score, I would like the players with the most recent scores (the ones for whom the ID is highest) to be stored before the older ones, so the older ones are discarded.

Essentially I need a way to sort an ArrayList by two fields- score first, low to high, then if the scores match sort those by the ID. Removing excess elements I already have mostly covered, although if there is a way to integrate that I would be interested to hear it.

EDIT: I'm trying to sort an Arraylist of objects with those attributes, not a single arraylist with them just thrown in. My bad.

Comment: Post the code you have written so far please.

Comment: And where are you stuck?

Comment: Can you just make a class to store your data that implements comparable https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html and then run the standard Collections.sort function?

Comment: The Java tutorial on [object ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) might help.

Comment: @mattias I didn't know of a way to sort on two fields. I only knew of a way to sort on one.

Answer (score 7):

If you use Java 8, there is a neat way of nesting comparators with method references:

```
List<Player> players = // ...

players.sort(Comparator
    .comparing(Player::getScore)
    .thenComparing(Player::getId));
```

More information can be found in the `Comparator` [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Comment: Java is suddenly so sexy, don't you love it? :)

Comment: @matsev I'm getting the errors:  The method comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U>) in the type Comparator is not applicable for the arguments (PlayerScore::getpilesRemaining),  The type PlayerScore does not define getpilesRemaining(Object) that is applicable here,  The type PlayerScore does not define getUniqueID(Object, Object) that is applicable here. Not sure what's up with it

Answer (score 3):

Don't use an ArrayList to hold your data.

Create a custom object with Id, name, score ... properties. Then you create a custom `Comparator`,

Here is an example of a simple custom Object and a custom Comparator. You would modify the Comparator to implement the logic that you just described.

```
/*
**  Use the Collections API to sort a List for you.
**
**  When your class has a "natural" sort order you can implement
**  the Comparable interface.
**
**  You can use an alternate sort order when you implement
**  a Comparator for your class.
*/
import java.util.*;

public class Person implements Comparable<Person>
{
    String name;
    int age;

    public Person(String name, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return name + " : " + age;
    }

    /*
    **  Implement the natural order for this class
    */
    public int compareTo(Person p)
    {
        return getName().compareTo(p.getName());
    }

    static class AgeComparator implements Comparator<Person>
    {
        public int compare(Person p1, Person p2)
        {
            return p1.getAge() - p2.getAge();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
        people.add( new Person("Homer", 38) );
        people.add( new Person("Marge", 35) );
        people.add( new Person("Bart", 15) );
        people.add( new Person("Lisa", 13) );

        // Sort by natural order

        Collections.sort(people);
        System.out.println("Sort by Natural order");
        System.out.println("\t" + people);

        // Sort by reverse natural order

        Collections.sort(people, Collections.reverseOrder());
        System.out.println("Sort by reverse natural order");
        System.out.println("\t" + people);

        //  Use a Comparator to sort by age

        Collections.sort(people, new Person.AgeComparator());
        System.out.println("Sort using Age Comparator");
        System.out.println("\t" + people);

        //  Use a Comparator to sort by descending age

        Collections.sort(people, Collections.reverseOrder(new Person.AgeComparator()));
        System.out.println("Sort using Reverse Age Comparator");
        System.out.println("\t" + people);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats wrong with ArrayList in this case? You can sort an ArrayList with a Comparator just fine.

Comment: @eckes, it the ArrayList contains the same data that is fine, but you should not use an ArrayList to hold different fields as the OP is describing. You create a custom object so you can have getters/setter for each field.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. It is an Arraylist of the custom object I'm trying to sort. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @camickr Ah yes, "Don't use a List of seperate entries for each field". Agreed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Collections.sort()

```
 Class Student{

   String fname="";
   String lname="";
   int age =0;
   int score=0;

   public Student(String fname,String lname,int age, int score)
   {
       this.fname=fname;
       this.lname=lname;
       this.age=age;
       this.score=score;
   }

  }
```

Sorting my list

```
    ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
     /*add elements*/
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Student>() 
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Student x, Student y)
        {
            if(x.score == y.score)
            {
                 return (y.age-x.age);
            }
            else 
                return (y.score-x.score);

        }
    });
```